# Condition of existence while solving inequalities

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I would like to have solutions of inequalities where condition of existence are included, but `Reduce` doesn't work like this, it would simplify the denominators before solving, like this:

```
Reduce[(x^2 + x)/x >= 0, Reals]
(* x >= -1 *)
```

Is there a way to have the solution with condition of existence of the original expression?

Comment: `Reduce[Exists[x, (x^2 + x)/x >= 0], Reals]` gives `True`. Is this what you need?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you mean:

```
Simplify[
  Reduce[(x^2 + x)/x >= 0, x] && FunctionDomain[(x^2 + x)/x, x]
]

(* Out: x >= -1 && x != 0 *)
```

Comment: Doesn't always work, for example with "FunctionDomain[x/x, x] " I get the output "True"

Comment: @MarcoDisce That's because `x/x` will immediately evaluate to 1. You could use `FunctionDomain[Hold[x/x], x]` instead, which prevents evaluation.